# Ошибка в cmake, программа компилируется без нужных флагов

Tags: cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(Tanks VERSION 0.1.0)

option(ENABLE_UNIT_TESTS "Enable unittest" ON)
message(STATUS "Enable testing: ${ENABLE_UNIT_TESTS}")

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/sdl2)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
if(NOT SDL2_IMAGE_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "SDL2_IMAGE NOT FOUND")
    return()
endif()

if(NOT SDL2_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "SDL2 NOT FOUND")
    return()
else()
    include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS} headers/)
    file(GLOB SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} "src/*.cpp")
    add_executable(main ${SOURCES})
    set_target_properties(main
                          PROPERTIES
                          ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
                          LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
                          RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
                          CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
                          CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17
                          CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17"
                          CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak" #<-- Нужный мне флаг! 
                          CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O2"
                         ) #<--Мотни скролбар снизу вправо, коммент выше не помещается
    target_compile_options(main PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}) #<-- Добавляю флаг!
    target_link_libraries(main 
                          ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} 
                          ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES})
    message(STATUS "Copy sprites folder")
    file(COPY Sprites DESTINATION .)
    if(ENABLE_UNIT_TESTS)   
        enable_testing()
        add_subdirectory(tests)
    endif()
endif()
```

Мне нужно собрать программу с флагом санитайзера, прочитал, добавил флаги в cmake, но 0 реакции, хочу разобраться, что же я делаю неверно.
Если запустить cmake командой:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak"
```

То все работает, я вижу вывод санитайзера, но что я прописал в cmake не так - понять не могу

Comment: ну дык, а собираешь то ты с `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`?? и к делу не относится, но проверки на `SDL2_FOUND` и `SDL2_IMAGE_FOUND` не нужны т.к. `find_package()` с параметром `REQUIRED` сам выбросит ошибку, если не найдёт их...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Ну я попробую так, как вы сказали запустить смаку, но! Я же просто в cmake добавляю эти флаги в target_compile_options. Мне бы по дефолту собирать с санитайзером, потом все нужные ифы добавлю на Debug и Release

Comment: @Fat-Zer т.е просто командой cmake .. чтоб собирался с санитайзером

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Различные ошибки, неточности и плохие практики

> ```
> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
> ```

`3.0.0` — это довольно древняя версия и, если нет особых причин придерживаться какой-либо более старой версии, хорошей практикой будет указывать версию CMake своей системы. В любом случае не стоит указывать ту версию, на которой сборка не тестировалась.

> ```
> if(NOT SDL2_IMAGE_FOUND)
> ```

т.к. `find_package` вызван с параметром `REQUIRED`, то эта проверка излишняя.

> ```
> file(GLOB SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} "src/*.cpp")
> ```

Использовать `GLOB` для получения списка исходников — плохая практика. См. примечание к [`file(GLOB ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob).

> ```
> set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES
>                       ...
>                       CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
>                       ...
> ```

*Свойства* с именем `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` и подобные не существуют. Есть одноимённые переменные СMake, но через `set_target_properties` их установить нельзя. Список свойств можно посмотреть в [`man 7 cmake-properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-properties.7.html).

> Мне бы по дефолту собирать с санитайзером

ИМХО это плохая практика. Санитайзер — тяжёлая и накладная штука и сборка с ним по умолчанию — неожиданный результат обычных действий.

---

#### Как бы я это сделал

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.5)
project(Tanks VERSION 0.1.0)

option(ENABLE_UNIT_TESTS "Enable unittest" ON)
option(ENABLE_SANITIZER "Pass -fsanitize=address and -fsanitize=leak to compiller" OFF)

message(STATUS "Enable testing: ${ENABLE_UNIT_TESTS}")

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/sdl2)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS} headers/)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -Wall -Wextra -pedantic")

if(ENABLE_SANITIZER) 
  string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak")
  string(APPEND CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS " -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak")
endif()

string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -Wall -Wextra -pedantic")

# Нет смысла задавать все эти переменные для каждой отдельной цели;
# если они нужны, то лучше сделать их общими
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")

set(SOURCES src/foo.cpp src/bar.cpp
            ...  # и другие исходники
)

add_executable(main ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(main 
                      ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} 
                      ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES})

message(STATUS "Copy sprites folder")
file(COPY Sprites DESTINATION .)
if(ENABLE_UNIT_TESTS)   
  enable_testing()
  add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()
```

Соответственно сборка с санитайзером будет выглядеть как

```
cmake /path/to/build -DENABLE_SANITIZER=ON
```

Если уж очень хочется включить сборку с санитайзаером по умолчанию, то можно поменять `OFF` на `ON` в объяввлении опции `ENABLE_SANITIZER`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! А то из книг и других черновых проектов в github нахватался и сам не знаю, как правильно писать cmake